# How can I temporary map a FTP server to a network folder?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I'm creating an application to synchronize a local folder on my computer with a FTP server.

Since I don't wan't to access the FTP server directly over it's address, because it would be really complicated, I wan't to map the server temporary to a network folder so that my synchronization algorithm can work on it like on a local folder.

Is there something like this:

```
//Map the server to the specified path
FtpMapper.MapFtpServer("ftp://myserver/", "username", "password", "M:\\");

DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("M:\\");

/* Do some work on the directory */

FtpMapper.UnmapFtpServer();
```

Comment: GNOME and KDE have this sort of facility built-in but Windows does not. You'd probably have to write it yourself.

Comment: Java has [Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/index.html), but there doesn't seem to be a .NET port.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1257671/16487) asks for an equivalent, but no takers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't such a library, as far as I know.

This requires a windows filesystem driver that understands FTP commands and a .NET wrapper over it.

I have seen such drivers (without a wrapper) as part of commercial FTP suites, but nothing open source or free.

Answer (score 0):

[NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/) boasts offering an SDK that lets you use it (netdrive) from your application. This is your only option if you don't want to write FTP code (or use third-party FTP component).

A programming solution to your task would be to take our [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/) (to create a virtual drive) and our [FTPSBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ftps.php) (FTP/FTPS components for .NET) and combine them in your application.